# Pagination in Android AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an AppWidget which performs these tasks in order

1. Get a user's current location. Use the coordinates & send a request to an API server.
2. API server will send a response in JSON format.
3. Using JSONObject, I manage to send the result to display via RemoteViews.

What I want to achieve here is that I want to implement a next & previous button (something similar like the official Twitter AppWidget) to change/move to the next item from the result. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

just save your json data in a sqlite table,and on your buttons click get data from table with set LIMIt.